# How to use dynamic AND or OR operator in where clause in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

```
DECLARE FILTER_DATA CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SELECT C_ID, C_NAME 
FROM DB2ADMIN.COURSES
WHERE C_ID = PARM_ID AND AND C_NAME = PARM_NAME
```

A procedure contains this cursor and the cursor have `AND` operator in `WHERE` clause, but I want to make this operator dynamic based on procedure parameter.

So that the cursor return resultset on the basis of either `AND` or `OR` operator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `where (C_ID = PARM_ID or PARM_ID is null) and ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic sql.

```
begin
  ...  
  DECLARE FILTER_DATA CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR s1;

  CASE PARM_FLAG
    WHEN 1 THEN
      PREPARE S1 FROM 'SELECT C_ID, C_NAME FROM DB2ADMIN.COURSES WHERE C_ID = ? AND C_NAME = ?';
    ELSE
      PREPARE S1 FROM 'SELECT C_ID, C_NAME FROM DB2ADMIN.COURSES WHERE C_ID = ? OR C_NAME = ?';
  END CASE;

  OPEN FILTER_DATA USING PARM_ID, PARM_NAME;
end@
```

If you expect `NULL` parameter input, you may do something like this for each statement:

```
PREPARE S1 FROM 'SELECT C_ID, C_NAME FROM DB2ADMIN.COURSES WHERE '
||case when PARM_ID is null then 'cast(? as int) is null' else 'C_ID = ?' end
||' AND '
||case when PARM_NAME is null then 'cast(? as varchar(1)) is null' else 'C_NAME = ?' end;
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the answer, this works for me fine, but when I pass null as one of the parameter with PARM_FLAG as AND then it return 0 resultset

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

Prepare/use a distinct SQL statement for each possible case/predicate (each possible kind of where clause) and pick the one to use based on the user input you're getting.

Technically, it is acceptable to write stuff like

`WHERE :PARM_ID IS NULL OR ID = :PARM_ID`

or

`WHERE (:CASE = 'OR' AND (C_1 OR C_2)) OR (:CASE = 'AND' AND (C_1 AND C_2))`

but you stand very little chance that it will also be acceptable performance-wise.  (You have a near guarantee of a full table scan for each single invocation.)

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for answering, I guess this only works when I want to skip any parameter while ANDing all the parameters where clause.